# get exact date time from x date time range

Tags: c#

Check the code bellow. In variable called- 'LastUpdatedAt' i am getting standard date time. Now my goal is i want to get the date time just 1 month back from this variable date. I already try to use DateTime.Now.AddMonths method but problem is i cant input my custom variable date on this method. Please tell me how can i get the date of 1 month back from that variable date? Screen shot attached for better understanding. [see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYHTE.png)

```
var LastUpdatedAt =  ctx.SearchedUsers.Where(x => x.SearchedUserID == item.SearchedUserID).FirstOrDefault().LastUpdatedAt;
DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
```

Comment: Do you want your variable to be lowered by one month?  If so, just do `LastUpdatedAt.AddMonths(-1)`.  Remember that AddMonths returns a DateTime so you have to assign the returned value to a variable (a new one or override LastUpdatedAt)

Comment: I tried that but problem is my variable LastUpdateAt not contains AddMonths(-1) this method.

Comment: Then `LastUpdateAt` is not a DateTime.  You need to provide a [MCVE] in your question, include the type of `LastUpdatedAt` (hint: dont use `var` unless its already clear what the type is, in your case it is _not_ clear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you may you need to make DateTime type. Then you can use AddMonths() method on it. Try the code below this might work for you.

```
var SearchedUsers =  ctx.SearchedUsers.Where(x => x.SearchedUserID == item.SearchedUserID).FirstOrDefault();
DateTime t = SearchedUsers.LastUpdatedAt.Value;
var outPut = t.AddMonths(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var LastUpdatedAt =  ctx.SearchedUsers.Where(x => x.SearchedUserID == item.SearchedUserID).FirstOrDefault().LastUpdatedAt;


DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(LastUpdatedAt, "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss tt",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

myDate .AddMonths(-1);
```